# Unable to copy an .exe to Start Menu folder

Tags: c++, copy, exe, codeblocks

I've been studying Java for about half a year and now I'm learning C++.
I'm using CodeBlocks with minGW and Win 8.1.

My problem is that I can copy an .exe file to the windows folder like this:

```
string str = string("copy " + currPath + " " + "C:\\\\Users\\\\Johan\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\ProgramCopy.exe");
```

I apologize if the code looks messy, but currPath is path of the .exe file and the other path is where I want to copy the .exe to.

But when I'm adding Start Menu after Windows it won't work. Like this:

```
string str = string("copy " + currPath + " " + "C:\\\\Users\\\\Johan\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start Menu\\\\ProgramCopy.exe");
```

I'm getting the error "the syntax of the command is incorrect". 
I searched for hours, I have tried to add a % and _ instead of space but still same error. I also tried running the program as admin but that wasn't the problem either.

I would appreciate any hint or suggestion I could get.

Here is what the str contains:

[image]

Comment: hint: show us what `str` contains.

Comment: I wonder if that is in any way C++ related at all or just an issue with the shell that is somewhere supposed to run those strings. BTW: Why do you have two backslashes separating each path element?

Comment: Sorry the image is ugly but I can not see anything worng, because it works without Start Menu.

Comment: @ulrichEckhardt I dont know I must have made a mistake there, maybe that is a problem?

Comment: You do know that a) you can copy text from a command window, and b) when posting an image, you don't have to capture your entire desktop. Right? IOW, there was absolutely no need to include an image at all in your post, and even if there were you could at least have the courtesy to crop it down to the minimal size needed. People trying to read this question on a mobile device are saying very unkind things right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second path contains space in it. You probably need to enclose the path in the "":

```
string str = string("copy " + currPath + " " + "\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Johan\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start Menu\\\\ProgramCopy.exe\"");
```

Comment: Well, arguments are white space separated, OS generally won't be able to guess that all of the sudden this one specific space shouldn't count. You might want to put quotes around currPath as well, if there is a chance it might contain spaces.

Comment: It's the way that command line parses the arguments. I assume that after you construct the string, you do something along the lines of `system(str);`. This will execute something like `copy ProgramCopy.exe c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\ProgramCopy.exe`, and the "copy" command thinks it got 3 parameters instead of expected 2.

Comment: Yes exactly i have "system(str.c_str());" I will have that in mind, really thank you! :)